# Android EditText not loading

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-fragmentactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
     * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not available.
     */
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason commenting out only the line:

```
//final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

then my application is functioning fine.

As soon as I add it back in:

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

the fragmentactivity fails to load and terminates with an error on the android device.

```
            06-13 18:52:07.924: E/Trace(28101): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.methanegaszonegeolocator/com.example.methanegaszonegeolocator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2012)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
            06-13 18:52:08.004: E/AndroidRuntime(28101):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
```

The line uncomments fine with no errors or warnings of any kind so I know I have the imports down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This boils down to not being able to call findViewById when the class instantiates.

You have to call that line in your onCreate method.

If you need access to it everywhere in your class then at the top of the class do:

```
final EditText editText;
```

Then in onCreate method do:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the following line inside the `onCreate` method.

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

So in your case, it would be...

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not available.
     */
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    final EditText editText; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // PASS YOUR LAYOUT HERE

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }
```